# How did Thanos achieve this?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame* (2019), when Avengers confront Thanos in "the Garden" and finds out that all the Infinity Stones are missing, he tells them that he used the "Stones" to destroy the "Stones". But how was he able to do that?

As per my assumption, he will be left with one last Infinity Stone regardless, how did he destroy that last Infinity Stone?

Comment: One stone didn't wipe other but a finger snap wiped them all

Comment: @AnkitSharma which is why there was only one cosmic activity mentioned after wiping half population?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As per my assumption, he will be left with one last Infinity stone regardless, how did he destroy that last Infinity stone?

You're assuming it required a *single* Stone to destroy others but that's not the case

It's clear that with **ALL** the Stones, Thanos can do **anything**....including destroying the Stones themselves.

In fact it's a plot point in *Endgame* that Thanos, with all the Stones, can destroy the *entire universe* and remake it in any way he wants.

Comment: I was assuming he used one stone to destroy others, like power stone to destroy soul stone, then maybe reality stone to destroy power stone etc. Thank you!